# How to Execute SPARQL Queries via EasyRdf?

Tags: php, virtuoso, easyrdf

I don't know, how to get a SPARQL query executed on the Virtuoso server via EasyRdf.

Virtuoso is started via

```
virtuoso\bin\virtuoso-t +service create +instance VirtuosoService
```

and I can go to http://localhost:8890/conductor on my web browser. In the tab *Linked Data/Graphs* there is a list of graphs:

- http://www.openlinksw.com/schemas/virtrdf#
- http://localhost:8890/sparql
- http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#
- http://localhost:8890/foaf

The latest is the graph wich I want to query and was created by uploading the file http://njh.me/foaf.rdf via *Quad Store Upload*.

Now comes the PHP part. What is the right way to execute a query via EasyRdf? The following code

```
$graph = new \EasyRdf_Graph('http://localhost:8890/foaf');
$numTriples = $graph->load();
```

throws this exception: **HTTP request for http://localhost:8890/foaf failed: File not found**

I also tested with

- `http://localhost:8890/foaf/sparql`: **HTTP request for http://localhost:8890/foaf/sparql failed: File not found**
- `http://localhost:1111/foaf/sparql`: **Failed to parse HTTP response.**
- `http://localhost:1111/foaf`: **Notice: fwrite(): send of 375 bytes failed with errno=10054** *An existing connection was closed by the remotehost*

Comment: I didn't use EasyRdf, but note, that Graph URI like: `http://localhost:8890/foaf` isn't a HTTP URL. The Virtuso sparql endpoint is `http://hostname:8890/sparql` by default. It is the endpoint for access to all graphs. For access to some special graph, the HTTP URL may be: `http://hostname:8890/sparql?default-graph-uri=http://localhost:8890/foaf`

Comment: @SergeyMalinin, thank you! I tried it with `$store = new \EasyRdf_GraphStore('http://localhost:8890/sparql'); $graph = $store->get('http://localhost:8890/foaf');`, but Virtuoso responses with '400 Bad Request, Virtuoso 22023 Error The request does not contain text of SPARQL query'. But Ok, maybe EasyRdf speaks another protocol than Virtuoso. I give [Erfurt](http://aksw.org/Projects/Erfurt.html) a try, that can communicate via ODBC.

Comment: SPARQL endpoints don't work that way. As pointed out by @SergeyMalinin, you can't just call the graph via EasyRdf and expect all triples. You **need** to ask the server (Virtuoso) to give you that number by using proper SPARQL. You should have a look at "http://vos.openlinksw.com/owiki/wiki/VOS/VOSSparqlProtocol" and "http://vos.openlinksw.com/owiki/wiki/VOS/VirtSPARQLReasoningTutorial". Also your friend is the GraphStore class, example: https://github.com/easyrdf/easyrdf/blob/master/test/FusekiTest.php#L88

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to write new data to sparql, I found this helpful :

replace : http://localhost:8890/sparql
with : http://localhost:8890/sparql-graph-crud

https://sourceforge.net/p/virtuoso/mailman/virtuoso-users/thread/8D306E7C-7361-433D-A7B8-0F8AA414FB0F%40gmail.com/#msg30383245